# Add a css class with Html.RouteLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know how I can add a class to the link rendered using the Html.RouteLink helper method in ASP.Net MVC, it has the htmlAttributes object as the last parameter which I assumed I would be able to use, but since class is obviously a reserved word, I cannot supply this as one of the properties on the object.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("Default", "Default",null, new { @class="css_class"}) %>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use uppercase for html attribute, like this:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink("Default", "Default",null, new { Class="css_class"}) %>
```

Comment: Yes that does work, but unfortunately this now means that my html no longer validate as xhtml strict due to the case.  Ideally I would like to find a solution which doesn't involve compromising the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in the c# specificaiton, the @ special character is used in front of a variable name to allow the use of keyword as a variable name.  So @class = "css_class" means setting value of the property called  "class" to css_class

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Robert, In my case(ASP.NET MVC) with razor syntax, I used it in another manner.

@Html.RouteLink("Default", "Default",null, new { @class="css_class"})